# Mac App Store claims newer version of my app is already installed

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, mac-app-store

I'm trying to install my app from the Mac App Store now that it's been published. I'm using the same machine as the one I developed the app one. For some reason, the App Store claims "A newer version of this app is already installed on this computer." I haven't touched the version number since I submitted it so this is strange.

I've removed all references of the app from Applications, Library/Preferences, Library/Application Support, Library/Caches, /var, and Trash. I've also cleaned the Product from within Xcode.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do a Spotlight search of the entire drive.  Check for earlier app names as well.  There may be an old build with the same app name or Bundle ID in yet another Derived Products or Build directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and delete your app's build folder.

Comment: This solution didn't solve the problem for me. I had issue the command mentioned in the other solution. Simon, it'd be great to accept that solution instead for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem with CoBook on Mountain Lion and nothing out there seemed to work until I found this:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

Source: http://web.archive.org/web/20130519023616/http://www.hacktheday.com/force-reinstall-application-downloaded-from-mac-app-store

Comment: Ran into this problem when compiling my own version of LiveReload. In addition to this, I also deleted all support files (the app itself,   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/, ~/Library/Preferences/,  ~/Library/Application Support/)

Answer (score 8):

To fix this problem, you need to perform two steps.

1. Delete all instances of your app. There are likely copies hiding in your home folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
2. Reset the `user` domain in the Launch Services database with
   `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain user`

The lsregister command manages the Launch Service database, or the database that keeps track of applications installed on your Mac and what types of files they open.

It's only necessary to reset the `user` domain (unlike the other answer from Mat E. that also resets the `system` and `local` domain) since your XCode DerivedData exists in your individual user directory. Only resetting this domain will prevent unnecessary warnings about running an app for the first time from reappearing.

Answer (score 0):

This happened again to me but unfortunately the other solutions didn't work. This is what ended up working:

1. Open the App Store. From the menu bar click Store > Sign In
2. Click Purchases from the top of the App Store window.
3. Select your app in the list. Then right or control click where you see Installed then click Install.
4. Make sure and use the same Apple ID used for the original purchase.

This also works for free apps.